# AntiDDOS protection slowing nginx server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

AntiDDOS slowing server

Hello, 
i just migrated from Apache24 to Nginx. OS on server is FreeBSD 10.3 (amd64) with custom kernel. I have one strange problem - when i uncomment this line in nginx config:

> limit_req zone=antiddosphp burst=5;

then wordpress dashboard load take >2s then with this option disabled. Where could be problem? Almost every page take more time to load with this option (or i dont know how to right set this)...

My second question is about right perormance setting in config file. My VPS is

> 1x 2Ghz + 2GB ram + 15gb ssd

Free memory after startup is about 1700 MB. Do i have right settings for nginx? I also have postfix, dovecot, mariadb and php-fpm installed. Mariadb take about 200M ram, MTA take about 150MB so i have about 1300 free for webserver.

My nginx conf file:

```
load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_mail_module.so;
load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_stream_module.so;

user  www;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;


   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=antiddosphp:10m rate=10r/s;
   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=antiddos:10m rate=10r/s;
   limit_req zone=antiddosphp burst=5;         

   server_tokens off;

   tcp_nopush      on;
   tcp_nodelay     on;
   sendfile        on;

   fastcgi_connect_timeout 100;
   fastcgi_send_timeout 100;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 100;
   fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
   fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
   fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
   fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 128k;
   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

   gzip on;
   gzip_min_length  1k;
   gzip_comp_level 9;
   gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/css application/xml;
   gzip_vary on;

   open_file_cache max=2000 inactive=60s;
   open_file_cache_valid 30s;
   open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
   open_file_cache_errors on;

   client_body_buffer_size   8k;
   client_header_buffer_size 16k;
   client_max_body_size 20m;
   client_body_timeout   10;
   client_header_timeout 10;
   large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

   keepalive_timeout     15;
   send_timeout          10;             
   keepalive_requests 1000;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/local/www/nginx;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;
        }

    }


  server {
      server_name test.test.cz;

      #limit_req zone=antiddos burst=60;      
      #limit_req zone=antiddosphp burst=2;

      access_log   /var/log/example.com.access.log;
      error_log    /var/log/example.com.error.log;

      root /usr/local/www/domains/test-cz/webserver/test;
      index index.php;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
      }
  }


}
```

PHP-FPM configuration:

```
user = www
group = www

pm = dynamic
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.max_children = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 200
request_terminate_timeout = 10
request_slowlog_timeout = 0
slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Thank you all for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are loading a website, you are not loading only this site, but assets as well. Nginx will think of them as independent connections. You have 10r/s defined and a burst size of 5. Therefore after 10 Requests/s the next requests will be delayed for rate limiting purposes. If the burst size (5) gets exceeded the following requests will receive a 503 error.

> If the requests rate exceeds the rate configured for a zone, their
>   processing is delayed such that requests are processed at a defined
>   rate. Excessive requests are delayed until their number exceeds the
>   maximum burst size in which case the request is terminated with an
>   error 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable).
>   (Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html)

**Answer:** Up the r/s a bit and the pages should flow out a bit faster.

For the second questions:
But i can't give a definit answer, just look at your load and determine if you have to tweak these values.

Usually the error log is a good start :)

Comment: You are right, setting higher values help a lot. Thank you.